# How to read the output of a previous command in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, bash-functions

I executed  a command in a shell script and the command  ends with "completed successfully" or "completed unsuccessfully". How can I read that in the script and use it for `if` and `else` conditions?

Comment: Does the command also set a reasonable exit status, or does it lie to the shell and say it succeeded when completing unsuccessfully?  (Check `$?`) If the command isn't a liar, you can just use `if <command>; then <stuff>; else <other stuff>; fi`

Comment: It's not really a duplicate of "assign command outputs to a var". OP may need to WATCH the output WHILE the command is running.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
your_command | \
tee >(sleep; [[ `tail -n1` =~ 'completed successfully' ]] && echo OK || echo NOTOK)
```

Explanation:

1. `tee`: split `your_command` outputs into two (i) `>(...)` and (ii) `stdout`
2. `sleep`: (optionally) wait for 1 second, change `1s` to what you need
3. `tail -n1`: extract last line
4. `=~`: matching test; change the test to what you need
5. `echo OK`, `echo NOTOK`: just examples, change to what you need